# Timstamp to Date time is (1488433367526 to 49136-07-30 06:42:06) in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I want to change Timestamp into Y-m-d H:i:s format

Here Am trying to achieve by doing following way :

```
 $current = date('Y-m-d');
        try
        {
            $data = array(
            'manager_id' => strval($custid),
            'punch_in_time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $intime),
            'punch_out_time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $outtime),
            'in_coordinates' => strval($inlocation),
            'out_coordinates' => strval($outlocation),
            'status' => $punchstatus,
            'create_at' => $current);   

 date formatted is 1488433367526 to 49136-07-30 06:42:06
```

also `$current` is in Mar 2, 2017 12:00:00 AM
format but time is not changing.

Comment: have you tried by strtotime

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: `1488433367526` is in milliseconds, so divide by 1000 and cast to int to get a unix timestamp - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/l2uJM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$intime` & `$outtime` are miliseconds. devide by `1000`. Here you go -

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (int)(1488433367526/1000));
```

**Output**

```
2017-03-02 05:42:47
```

[Working code](https://eval.in/746068)

Comment: can u plz tell me if i want to convert date to timestamp in php

Comment: `strtotime()` should help.

Answer (score 0):

you have the miliseconds, check the [demo](https://eval.in/746069).

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1488433367526 / 1000);
```

Comment: I Think it may cause the issue as my db data type for these columns is varchar(30) . Is it ??

Comment: You may use the type timestamp here.

Comment: I think I should modify the Datatype just trying..  Thanks a lot!!